# Finite sum involving Stirling number of first kind and Pochhammer symbol

Tags: summation, stirling-numbers, pochhammer-symbol

I'm trying to find a closed form of

$$\sum_{m=0}^n\,s(n,m)\,(\alpha)_m\,z^m$$

where $(\alpha)_m$ means pochhammer symbol and $s(n,m)$ are the Stirling numbers of first kind.

I've had a look in related books but I have not luck.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited

Comment: Stirling N. 1st kind , signed or unsigned ? Pochammer = Rising or Falling factorial ?

Comment: Pochammer=rising factorial  $(x)_n=x(x+1)...(x+n-1)$ and $s(n,m)$ note the signed Stirling numbers of first kind

Comment: ok, so put these clarifications directly into your post

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite your sum as
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(z,n,\alpha ) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k}
 \left[ \matrix{  n \cr  k \cr}  \right]\alpha ^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } z^{\,k} }
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k}
 \left[ \matrix{  n \cr  k \cr}  \right]z^{\,k} \alpha ^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^n \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
 {\left[ \matrix{  n \cr   k \cr}  \right]z^{\,k} \left( { - \alpha } \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } }
  = \left( { - 1} \right)^n \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
 {k!\left[ \matrix{  n \cr   k \cr}  \right]z^{\,k} \left( \matrix{   - \alpha  \cr  k \cr}  \right)}  \cr} 
$$
where

- $\alpha ^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }$ represents the [Rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials);
- $ \left[ \matrix{  n \cr  k \cr}  \right]$ represents the unsigned Stirling N. 1st kind.

I can't provide at the moment a closed formula for that, but considering the well known
[e.g.f. for the Stirling N. 1st kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Generating_functions)
$$
{1 \over {m!}}\left( {\ln \left( {{1 \over {1 - x}}} \right)} \right)^{\,m}
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left[ \matrix{  k \cr   m \cr}  \right]\,{{x^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} 
$$

we can get this e.g.f.
$$
\eqalign{
  & G(z,y,\alpha ) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {F(z,n,\alpha ){{y^{\,n} } \over {n!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{k!} \over {n!}}
\left[ \matrix{  n \cr  k \cr}  \right]\left( { - y} \right)^{\,n} z^{\,k} \left( \matrix{   - \alpha  \cr   k \cr}  \right)} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n}
 {\left[ \matrix{  n \cr  k \cr}  \right]{{\left( { - y} \right)^{\,n} } \over {n!}}} } \right)k!z^{\,k}
 \left( \matrix{   - \alpha  \cr   k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k}
 {\left( \matrix{   - \alpha  \cr  k \cr}  \right)\left( {\ln \left( {{1 \over {1 + y}}} \right)} \right)^{\,k} z^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {1 + z\ln \left( {{1 \over {1 + y}}} \right)} \right)^{\, - \alpha }
  = {1 \over {\left( {1 - z\ln \left( {1 + y} \right)} \right)^{\,\alpha } }} \cr} 
$$

which means
$$
F(z,n,\alpha ) = \left. {{\partial^n  \over {\partial y^n}}
{1 \over {\left( {1 - z\ln \left( {1 + y} \right)} \right)^{\,\alpha } }}\;} \right|_{\,y\, = \,0} 
$$

Comment: @metamorphy : thanks for correcting .. :)